# Flutter/iOS: Integrated plugin requests camera permission which is not required in app

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

In my iOS/Flutter app, I am using a QR reader plugin. My requirement is to recognize QR data from images only, not from the camera. But the plugin offers both.

So, I don't need the camera permission in my app and therefore I didn't add this to the `Info.plist` file.

Unfortunately, Apple refused the app due to `Missing Purpose String: NSCameraUsagePermission`.

Because I also integrated the plugin `permission_handler`, I have already added this to my `podfile`:

```
  config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
    '$(inherited)',

    ...

    ## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
    'PERMISSION_CAMERA=0',

    ...
  ]
```

I thought this helps me with exactly the described issues: Add permission, a plugin requests but is not required in my app. Obviously, it does not.

Is there a way to achieve that: Deny the camera permission while using the requesting plugin nonetheless?

Answer (score 1):

Last time I had an issue like this I wrote the permission description in the `info.plist` and made it explicit that the permission was not used. In your case it should be something like this.

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Not used but enfored by a dependency</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Read QR codes from saved images</string>
```

And apple did accepted my app despite that. It should be fine as long as you are explicit with it.
If they do reject it I would probably fork the plugin and drop the Permission in the code.

Comment: Yes, indeed this is my intermediate solution. But I really search for a better one... Thank you nonetheless :)

Comment: Good luck!, but as plugins are designed in flutter I do not believe a better one exists.

Answer (score 0):

As per [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) guidelines you have to mark all those permission as commented which you are not using in the app.

---

As per plugin guidelines, Remove the # character in front of the permission you do want to use. For example, if you need access to the camera make sure the code looks like this:

```
 ## dart: PermissionGroup.calendar
   'PERMISSION_CAMERA = 1',
```

---

In your case, you have added `'PERMISSION_CAMERA=0'` in `podfile`, So Apple expected permission for the camera in `info.plist` file and it's missing over there. So update your `podfile` as below.

```
config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
        '$(inherited)',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.calendar
        # 'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1',
]
```

**Note:** Whatever permission you are making uncommented in `podfile`, make sure you add permission for the same in `info.plist` file and also add a proper description(purpose of using that permission in your app).

Comment: Are your quite sure about it? I am pretty sure that 'PERMISSION_CAMERA = 0' is no permission. It already worked until I added my QR plugin. Before that, no issue raised. So, I am sure although the Podfile was as it is. So without the additional plugin and with 'CAMERA=0' everything was fine. So, as already stated, I have no issue with the permission_handler but the new plugin.

Comment: @S-Man Please check setup guidelines of Permission-handler. https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler#setup

Comment: @S-Man Also they have done some changes in `podfile` setup for permissions. Please check the changelog of version 8.0.0: https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler/changelog#800 Also I have edited the answer as well for your clear understanding.

Comment: Yes, as you can see in your linked document they state "e.g. when you don't need camera permission, just add 'PERMISSION_CAMERA=0'" which is exactly what I did. So, I am still sure, that for permission handler everything is fine but not with my QR plugin...

Comment: @S-Man please either you are using permission or not... you have to add all the permission groups in the podfile... the only thing you have to take care of in your case is just make `PERMISSION_CAMERA = 1` commented not `PERMISSION_CAMERA = 0` and make sure you don't have `NSCameraUsagePermission` in your `info.plist` file it will fix your problem surely.

Comment: Once more ;) `PERMISSION_CAMERA = 1` *enables* the permission according to the docs: https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler#setup I want to *disable* it. That's why it is set to `0` (which is correct acc. to the in the documentation linked podfile: https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/blob/master/permission_handler/example/ios/Podfile) Moreover, this macro is ONLY for `permission_handler` plugin, not for my newly added *QR plugin*, isn't it? So I have no issue with the preprocessor macro, it's ok, I believe. I need to tell the QR plugin, not to use the permission.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237833/discussion-between-dhaval-kansara-and-s-man).